# Is this vector function linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, applications

I am having problems in understanding the following exercise: $$F: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2; \qquad F(x) = (2x, 3y)$$
I have to say if it's linear.

I am having troubles in understanding where does the $y$ come from. Anyway, Shall I prove by linearity that

$$F(x_1 + x_2) = F(x_1) + F(x_2)$$ hence

$$F(x_1 + x_2) = (2(x_1 + x_2), 3y) = (2x_1 + 2x_2, 3y)$$

I think by sum of vectors that I cannot say that the previous is linear since it should be

$$(2x_1, 3y) + (2x_2, 3y)$$

Which is false.

Am I right?

Comment: the $y$ makes no sense. It doesn't belong. The only input is x.

Comment: Or it is a trick question of the form "for which $y$ is the function $F$ linear?"...

Comment: @JonasLinssen No trick question. I only have to prove if that function is linear or not, via the definition

Comment: As @311411 says, the $y$ makes no sense. If you assume it is some fixed number different from $0$ then your argument showing the function is not linear is correct.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you!!

Comment: Whereas if $y=0,$ it is linear but you have not yet finished to prove it ($F(\lambda x)=\dots$). Note also that for $y\ne0,$ you just have to notice that F(0)=(0,y)\ne(0,0).$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you Anne. Indeed there is no specification in the notes, hence the condition $y = 0$ has to be treated. And for $y = 0$ it's linear indeed. I was just perplexed about that $y$, since $F = F(x)$. But it's all clear now!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered in the comments.

Comment: Could've also been a typo (meant $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ given by $F(x,y)=\cdots$).

Comment: Maybe  $F(x) = (2x, 3x)$?

Answer (score 0):

You should understand $y$ as being a fixed constant i.e. its value does not change when the value of the variable $x$ changes.

To check linearity let $x,x' \in \mathbb R$, then:

$$ F(x + x') = F(x)+F(x') \iff (2x+2x',3y) = (2x,3y) + (2x',3y)$$

$$ \iff 3y = 6y$$

$$ \iff y = 0.$$

So the property $F(x+x') = F(x)+F(x')$ is only verified if $y = 0$.

If $y = 0$ then

$$ F(\lambda x) = \iff (2\lambda x,0) = \lambda (2x,0) = \lambda F(x).$$

Hence the map is not linear when $y \neq 0$ and linear when $y = 0$.